# How to use pdb(or other tools) to debug trace function?

Tags: python, pdb

Consider a simple example

```
def g(x):
    return x

def tracer(frame, event, arg):
    import pdb
    pdb.set_trace()
    print("\nthis is global")  # didn't stop here
    print(frame, event, arg)

sys.settrace(tracer)
g(2)
```

I would like to stop **inside** the trace function so I can debug it, however it doesn't seem to work. I know this is because pdb also uses `sys.settrace`, so they can have conflicts.

The question is, how to debug trace function? Can we use pdb or is there any other option?

Comment: From `Python 3.7`, you can use `breakpoint()`.

Comment: @SukumarRdjf `breakpoint()` doesn't help, it's the same thing as pdb.

Comment: I think you just need to run that function... by `tracer(1, 2, 3)` instead of using `sys.settrace(tracer)`.

Comment: @Sraw But that changes the intention of the program.

Comment: Hum... Sorry, I understand. You are trying to debug a debugger. As far as I think, it is impossible without a lower level debugger.

Comment: Checking out [pdb/bdb](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/bdb.py) you can see that `pdb.set_trace()` does indeed call `sys.settrace` (line 334), which would definitely throw a wrench in what you're trying to do. I think you're going to have a lot of trouble putting a debugger in the trace function, but I would recommend reading these [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) more closely. Your function `tracer` doesn't differentiate events at all, so the `print` statements will cause infinite recursion.